# FxCop error in TeamCity Sonar Runner step

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, fxcop, sonar-runner

I am running SonarQube Runner step with the following additional parameters.

> -X
>   -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
>   -Dsonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=%config.solution.file.path%
>   -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
>   -Dsonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop/FxCopCmd.exe

However for a larger solution, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to set 3 options to make fxcop work

```
-Dsonar.cs.fxcop.assembly=PathToDllFromSolution
-Dsonar.fxcop.installDirectory=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop
-Dsonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Team Tools/Static Analysis Tools/FxCop/FxCopCmd.exe
```